# Pass argument to readable store in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-store

is there someway to pass an argument to readable store in svelte ? I have the next code:

```
export const worker = readable(
    [], async (set) => {

        const response = await fetchAPI()
        set(response)
        
        const interval = setInterval(async () => {
            const response = await fetchAPI()
            set(response)
        }, 10000)
})
```

I want pass an argumeto to that readable function with the response of the api to set the result of it via set().

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access any variables that are in scope, so you can "pass" a variable from outside the `readable`'s function.

```js
export function worker(arg) {
   return readable([], async set => {
      const response = await fetchAPI(arg); // arg is in scope here
      // ...
   });
}
```

Comment: Yeah I just was trying it same i just resolve creating a function and return the readable. Thanks anyway @H.B. +1